# How to get access_token from ADP Api using rest?

Tags: adp

Hi I'm tryinng to get access token using the below post URL `https://accounts.adp.com/auth/oauth/v2/token?grant_type=client_credentials&scope=api`   and I'm setting basic authorization in header. While requesting I get 401 error.

```
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "proper client ssl certificate was not presented"
}
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you will need to resolve the issue of ADP issued client certificate first. https://developers.adp.com/articles/general/introduction-mutual-ssl (Mutual TLS/SSL Help from ADP Dev Site). You will need to contact your ADP support team if they have not issued you a client API (SSL) cert yet.